# Angular 4 using highcharts gauge

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm using *angular 4 (4.4.4), "highcharts": "~6.0.1", "angular2-highcharts": "~0.5.5"*.

It displays simple chart well but getting the following errors displaying gauge

[image]

As suggesions from other posts I have the following code in appmodule.ts

```ts
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';

declare var require : any;

export function highchartsFactory() {
  const highcharts = require('highcharts');
  const highChartsMore = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
  const solidGauge = require('highcharts/modules/solid-gauge');
  ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'),
        require('highcharts/highcharts-more'),
        require('highcharts/modules/solid-gauge'));
  return highcharts;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: check this plunker forked from official example http://plnkr.co/edit/tLK6seWvqYBAl3QA7ayF?p=preview

Comment: Errors says that the series definition is not loaded or there might be a typo in your code - series names are case sensitive. (FYI: angular2-highcharts is great wrapper, but it's not an official Highcharts wrapper)

Comment: Thank you so much Kacper. This example works. The only thing cli complains is duplicate yAxis definition, but that can be solved easily. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Include extra modules required for gauge charts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule, Component }    from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }          from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ChartModule }            from 'angular2-highcharts'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: [`
      chart {
        display: block;
      }
    `],
  template: `<chart [options]="options"></chart>`
})
class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge'
      },
      title: null,
      pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {

          innerRadius: '60%',
          outerRadius: '100%',
          shape: 'arc'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      },
      // the value axis
      yAxis: {
        stops: [
          [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
          [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
          [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickAmount: 2,
        title: {
          y: -70
        },
        labels: {
          y: 16
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        title: {
          text: 'Speed'
        }
      },
      plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
          dataLabels: {
            y: 5,
            borderWidth: 0,
            useHTML: true
          }
        }
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },

      series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
      }]
    };
  }
  options: Object;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ChartModule.forRoot(
      require('highcharts'),
      require('highcharts/modules/exporting'),
      require('highcharts/highcharts-more'),
      require('highcharts/modules/solid-gauge')
    )
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
class AppModule {}


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0rK9IENiYB12BGJp9Fz5) Demo

Comment: followed this guide but getting this error ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ChartModule', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule

Comment: Thanks for your response @Deep, I am using angular CLI and trying with AOT build, is there any help you can do for me?

Comment: ChartModule.forRoot(...) should work. i am using this in angular 4 project it gives no problem

Comment: I am not sure what is my problem @deep, I have had enough of different ways for past two days and none worked. Now I removed 3rd party libraries and only using highcharts with ViewChild and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Install highcharts-more 

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as ChartModuleMore from 'highcharts-more'; 
ChartModuleMore(Highcharts);
```

Comment: While this code may  answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.